# scanning barcode in android without using intent

Tags: android

I want to create barcode scanner in android .Is there any sample example for this. I have tried using intent and i got the barcode but for this we need to install barcode scanner in android mobile.I do not want to use  the downloaded barcode scanner in my application.I got the zxing.zip file but it is not clear to understand to make barcode scanner application.Is there any simple example that just scan barcode .

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of barcode scanning libraries. The three I can recommend are:

- Scandit http://www.scandit.com/
- RedLaser: http://redlaser.com/
- ZXing (very rough) : http://code.google.com/p/zxing/.

Scandit is pretty young but their algorithms are very, very good, IMHO better than Redlaser's (Redlaser is owned by eBay now).  Both Scandit and Redlaser are pricey for commercial use, but scandit has an ad-run free version. Zxing on the other hand is open source and fully free to use but it has much worse quality especially when scanning in non-perfect-lab conditions (rounded shapes, reflection barcodes a little worn etc.).

Comment: thanks jarek.I tried by executing android  client (scanner) after adding required core classes in android(scanner) and application is getting opened but not giving the result

Comment: Now i am getting the scanner work very well.Earlier i did not get the result as i have mention in above comment. this is because in dim light zxing  library wont work well But in bright light like in night in tubelight i getting the result very quickly within a  couple of seconds.

Comment: It's definitely better to use intent and to suggest some scanner app inside your application (if there is none present). This way, you don't have to bother with any updates in scanning libraries, you also let the user decide, which scanning application they want to use.

Even one of the devs of ZXing library suggested that: http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/#comment-159

Comment: I would not be so "definitive" about it. Intents are a good way to execute certain tasks - sending an email for one, or open a web page in a browser and a number of others. However if your app's core  functionality is scanning a QR code and doing something about it (say for finding products and compare prices) then deferring to another application through intent is not good. You leave your app, when the user has more than one qr app - it gives them the extra "select" dialogue, you cannot really add your own app-specific experience. I see a lot of cases where library is better choice